# Refreshing page or making it to respond after downloading the file. All happening in Webpart

Tags: 2010, visual-web-part, gridview

I'm having a Visual Webpart that allows user to select Managed Properties and find out what is stored inside it. The result is displayed inside a gridview which he/she can export it to excel.

It is same another export to excel code that I have written:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
string filename = "Report_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss") + ".xls";
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + filename);
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
GridView tempGridView = new GridView();
tempGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
string strContents = getGridViewHtml(GetExportingGridView(tempGridView));
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(strContents);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

But after the file is downloaded the page stops responding to any events.

I cannot have one more (dummy) page which can take this request and make a download operation and go off.

Any work around for this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I just figured it out.

We are just making the export button not to act like a form submit button.

Below is the code for this.

```
  btnExport.UseSubmitBehavior = false;
  btnExport.OnClientClick = "_spFormOnSubmitCalled = false; _spSuppressFormOnSubmitWrapper=true;";
```

Comment: Of course not having submit the form always helps. Good find.

Answer (score 5):

I have put your code in the page load event and it resolves the issue.

```
btnExport.UseSubmitBehavior = false;
btnExport.OnClientClick = "_spFormOnSubmitCalled = false; 
_spSuppressFormOnSubmitWrapper=true;";
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on my last project.
The main problem is sharepoint catches form submits and downloads so you cannot double click a button.

So I added this to the page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    _spOriginalFormAction=document.forms[0].action;
    _spSurppressFormOnSubmitWrapper = true;
</script>
```

I Think that fixed that issue, but I ended up using the SharePoint download page:

/_layouts/download.aspx?sourceurl=[file url]&source=[current page]

Comment: Hi Thantos, thanks for the quick reply. So do you mean that merely pasting that script will not work ? I need to use the download.aspx page as well ? If yes then, I didn't understand what do you mean by [file url] as my code is just exporting the gridview content to excelsheet. Also [current page] ? you mean the just "audit.aspx" or the entire URL ? thanks.

Comment: Just try the code, if you are just exporting the data directly, the download page won't work for you, only if it was a sp library doc, so try the script.

Comment: Thantos. Thanks for the reply.. just figured out the solution for this. You may check and comment. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The following link was very helpful in understanding the response issue that I was facing. It was solved by setting a few flags.

http://mytechsoup.com/?p=36